# If a non-primitive attribute is declared as final can I make assumptions about its state (count on a given state in a given moment)?

Tags: java, final

Assuming its reference its exposed by a getter method.

Hi, I am new here. I am first year university student doing a bachelor in informatics.
In one of my weekly assignments I came upon this question, which I don't know the asnwer to.
Could someone please help me??

Comment: After construction, you can assume that it always points to the value it was assigned in the constructor. You can't assume anything about the state of that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: No.
Final means that you cannot change object to which the reference points, but it says nothing about that object's internal state.

In other words - you cannot modify final reference, but you can modify the object it references.